# How to find recent questions without answers and comments

Tags: support, questions, search-box

I am wondering how to find questions where people really need help?

I mean that these should most like be questions which don't have answers yet, not closed, created recently (not already forgotten by the authors), and not accepted as solved.

I tried the following request:

```
isaccepted:no answers: 0 created: 3d closed: no
```

but as the second line got the response:
[How is a 3d perlin noise function used to generate terrain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091468/how-is-a-3d-perlin-noise-function-used-to-generate-terrain)
which have answers and one of them is already accepted.

Questions:

1. What I did wrong and how to improve the search query?
2. Is there a way to find questions without comments? (Since I suppose that they most challenging and people need help there most).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You need to remove the space after the operators. For example: `answers: 0` should be `answers:0`.
2. You should remove `isaccepted:no` - it only applies to answers and you only want questions.
3. Add `is:question` or `is:q` to filter to only questions.

This gives you the query `answers:0 created:3d closed:no is:question` [link to results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+created%3A3d+closed%3Ano+is%3Aquestion).

---

There is no way to filter to questions without comments. Not in search.

You can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) to find questions without comments but the data is only synchronised once a week on Sunday. So, you will not get recent questions unless you use a query on Monday/Tuesday and even then you will not get their latest state, so it is not a very viable option.